# Referencing JS in master page: Using MS and ME tags versus not using them

Tags: 2013, javascript, custom-masterpage, scriptlink

I've seen scripts referenced in 2 ways.  What is the purpose of the MS and ME tags?  Use them or not?

```
<!–MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID=”ScriptLink21″ Name=”sp.js” runat=”server” OnDemand=”false” LoadAfterUI=”true” Localizable=”false”>–>
<!–ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>–>
```

versus

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink21" Name="sp.js" runat="server" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 has introduced new way of editing Master pages, i.e. you change/work on HTML version of the master page and SharePoint will automatically convert it into .master file

Now since HTML will not support SharePoint controls or other server side controls.. You can comment them using MS and ME tags.. where

MS = markup start
ME = markup end

In this way SharePoint understands that this is a server-side control within HTML master page file and removes the comments when converting to .master file

So if you are working directly on .master file, you do not need to include MS and ME tags.. Those are only helpful when you are working on HTML file and want server-side controls to be converted correctly..

Read more here

[How to: Convert an HTML file into a master page in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822370(v=office.15).aspx)